# Inequality for bounded probability density functions

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions

I'm currently reading [these](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Eyw562/teaching/it-stats.pdf) Lecture Notes on Information-Theoretic methods in High Dimensional Statistics. In the proof of the upper bound in Lemma 17.1 (top of page 106), the author makes the following claim:

> ...It is known that for any bounded pdf $f$ and $g$, \begin{equation*}
>  \|f-g\|_{1}^{2} \gtrsim\|f-g\|_{2}^{2}, \end{equation*}

I have the following four queries on this claim:

1. Are $f, g$ assumed to be densities on a **common** probability support, say $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$, for any fixed $d \in \mathbb{N}$. That is, does the author assume that $\mathsf{supp}(f) = \mathsf{supp}(g) = G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$.
2. If yes to 1, then are there any restrictions on the support set $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$, e.g., must be finite, or can it be compact, unbounded etc? And is $d \in \mathbb{N}$ correct, or does $G \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ only, i.e., $f, g$ are *univariate* densities?
3. I assume that by 'bounded pdf', the author means that $|f(x)| \leq M, |g(x)| \leq m$, for some fixed $m, M>0$, and $| \cdot |$ is the Euclidean metric, is this correct? If so does $m = M$ here?
4. How does one prove this claim? I could not find a proof in the literature for it, and it seems to be referred to as a well known claim.

Could anyone please answer the above questions?